# Weird Jittering Effect Going On With Model?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, edit-mode, shaders, artifacts

So I have a 3D Model of Godzilla, and so far everything is great with it. The only problem is this weird effect going on near Godzilla's mouth area where the lighting seems to be jittering. I don't know if this is an edit mode problem, or if it is with the material, but are there any ideass? Thank you!

[image: godzilla gif]

Comment: Please add the corresponding renderer tag of the renderer you're using (EEVEE, Cycles, ...)

Comment: Seems like you have overlapping faces on the model (they are fighting which one should be rendered in the front) Try merging verticies. In edit mode`Alt`+'M' + `By distance`

Comment: Thank you, this seems to have helped after I carefully selected which faces seem to be making the problem, then setting the distance at .02!